# What should you be aware of when planning late-season or summer skiing?

Tags: skiing

Until now, all my skiing has been during the (local) winter. I recently had a spare day while in Switzerland, and found that [one of the nearby resorts was still open](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16712/26), so for the first time I tried some late season skiing.

Some aspects of the skiing were the same as I'm used to, but some things were surprisingly different, and I wished I'd known about that beforehand so I could've planned better. (The biggest two were around the amount of water I'd need to drink, and how much the snow changed during the day)

Aiming at someone with some winter skiing experience, trying out late season (or perhaps even summer) skiing for the first time, what do you need to be aware of?

Comment: One piece of advise: Don't wear the "typical" resort ski gear, i.e., a thick jacket and these super-warm pants. Get a layered system so you don't overheat.

Comment: My experience with warm weather skiing: ski; damage your skis on rocks; cry; repeat.

Answer (score 7):

The snow melts some days (or most days) in the late season. If it refreezes at night, it will be icy in the morning, making icy or rough skiing.

When the snow gets slushy in the afternoon, you will get much wetter than in the cold weather. The skiing will be a little slower, too, and you may be surprised by hidden rocks since your skis are digging in deeper on the turns.

Comment: I'd add that kneeling in the snow or falling means you'll get much wetter than you would in the winter, so although it's tempting to wear spring/summer clothing, you'll want at least your pants to be Gore-tex or similar. Wool is a good choice for your top if you want to breath in the heat.